# hide and show div every x time AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm having troubles to hide and show a div that works as an alert to my application.

Currently I'm using the $interval for make this a permanent hide and show action, but the result I'm expecting is that the DIV remains visible X time and then hide the same X time.

Here is how I0'm doing it now:

```
   function showNotification(idNotification) {
       $('[id*=noti_]').addClass('dis_none');
       $('#noti_' + idNotification).removeClass('dis_none');
   }

   function hideNotification() {
       // $('#noti_' + idNotification).addClass('dis_none');
       $('[id*=noti_]').addClass('dis_none');
   }

   function checkCalendar() {
       var tomorrow = moment().add(1, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
       WebApiFactory.GetShiftPeriod("BodyShop", "2017-11-07").then(function (data) {
           // WebApiFactory.GetShiftPeriod("BodyShop", tomorrow).then(function (data) {
           if(data[0].TargetPlantValue === 0){
               showNotification("alert");
           }
       });
   }

   function notifications(type, time) {
       switch (type) {
           case "calendar":
               // checkCalendar();
               $interval(function () {
                   checkCalendar();
                   console.log("Active");
               },time * 1000);
               $interval(function () {
                   hideNotification();
                   console.log("Hide");
               }, time * 1001);


               break;
       }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but if you want to show the dialog for some 'x' time, and then hide it, you shouldn't start both intervals at the same time. Just wait when the dialog is shown and then start a timer for hiding it.

For example if you need to hide the timer after a '100' ms.

```
function notifications(type, time) {
     switch (type) {
         case "calendar":
              $interval(function () {
                   checkCalendar();
                   $timeout(hideNotification, 100);
              }, time * 1000);
         break;
     }
}
```

Also be aware that I used a `$timeout` directive here. It's almost the same as `$interval` but will be invoked only once.

> how can I make that the time that the div is shown is the same as the
>   time when is hide

It's a bit trickier, so let's use another algorithm.
There we just have a single $interval, but keep a current state `isNotificationActive` and show/hide the element according to this state.

Also be aware that I use `$interval.cancel` to stop a previous launched interval, if you have one.

```
var notificationInterval = null,
    isNotificationActive = false;

function notifications(type, time) {
     switch (type) {
         case "calendar":
              $interval.cancel(notificationInterval);
              notificationInterval = $interval(updateNotificationState, time * 1000);
         break;
     }
}

function updateNotificationState() {
     if(isNotificationActive) {
         //hide the element here;
     } else {
         //show the element here;
     }
     isNotificationActive = !isNotificationActive;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the $timeout option.

Comment: Just one more question, how can I make that the time that the div is shown is the same as the time when is hide.

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this ...

Make your notification element(s) "responsible" for hiding themselves, as follows :

```
function showNotification(idNotification, hideAfter) {
    var $el = $('#noti_' + idNotification);
    $timeout.cancel($el.data('timoutRef')); // kill latent auto-hide (if scheduled)
    $el.removeClass('dis_none'); // show
    if(hideAfter) {
        // Schedule auto-hide after `hideAfter` milliseconds,
        // and keep a reference to the timeout so it can be cleared.
        $el.data('timoutRef', $timeout(function() {
            $el.addClass('dis_none'); // hide
        }), hideAfter);
    }
}
```

Now adjust `checkCalendar()` and `notifications()`

```
function checkCalendar() {
    WebApiFactory.GetShiftPeriod("BodyShop", "2017-11-07").then(function (data) {
        if(data[0].TargetPlantValue === 0) {
            // Make sure the value passed below is one half the total cycle time
            showNotification("alert", 1000/2); // show immediately, hide after 1/2 second
        }
    });
}

function notifications(type, time) {
    switch (type) {
        case "calendar":
            // Here, everything can be nice and simple
            $interval(checkCalendar, time * 1000); // total cycle time
        break;
    }
}
```

Providing your various notification elements don't try to occupy the same real-estate on screen, you (probably) don't need to worry about hiding other notifications.

If the notification elements *do* try to occupy the same real-estate, you need to consider reducing their number to just one.